# Python urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, scrapy, urllib2

I have wrote python 2.7 script for save page content of requested page into a specific file the script is

```
import scrapy
import os
import urllib2

class hTMLCODEaMAZONE(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'HTMLCODE'
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

    st_urls = [
      'https://www.amazon.co.uk/VSafety-12034AN-G-Proceed-Assembly-Portrait/dp/B01NBC6659/ref=sr_1_2096?s=diy&rps=1&ie=UTF8&qid=1491382440&sr=1-2096',
      'https://www.amazon.co.uk/VSafety-13014AF-R-Equipment-Plastic-Square/dp/B01NBC5ZXM/ref=sr_1_2097?s=diy&rps=1&ie=UTF8&qid=1491382440&sr=1-2097',
    ]

    for link in st_urls:
        response = opener.open(link)
        results(response)

    def results(response):
        FNAME = str(response.url)

        s = FNAME.split('/dp/')[1]
        FFNAME = s.split('/ref')[0] + '.html'

        f = open(FFNAME,'w')
        f.write(str(response.read))
        f.close()

        file_info = os.stat(FFNAME)
        fsize = file_info.st_size

        # yield {
          # 'pagelink': response.url,
          # 'file size':fsize,
        # }
```

when i run this i got an error when i run script into windows powershell

```
PS G:\AMAZON FILES> scrapy runspider .\HTMLCODE.py
2017-04-16 12:46:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: 
scrapybot)
2017-04-16 12:46:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: 
{'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
  "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 142, in 
  execute
  _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 88, in 
  _run_print_help
  func(*a, **kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149, in 
  _run_command
  cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\runspider.py", line 
  80, in run
  module = _import_file(filename)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\runspider.py", line 
  21, in _import_file
  module = import_module(fname)
  File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
  __import__(name)
  File "G:\AMAZON FILES\HTMLCODE.py", line 5, in <module>
  class hTMLCODEaMAZONE(scrapy.Spider):
  File "G:\AMAZON FILES\HTMLCODE.py", line 17, in hTMLCODEaMAZONE
  response = opener.open(link)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 429, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
  '_open', req)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
  context=self._context)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)>
```

and i need to store FFNAME and fsize variable's values into .csv file for the record i have tried this with urllib.request.urlopen() but still gave this error